# Attach security groups to multiple EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, automation, aws-cli, security-groups

Is it possible to attach a new security group to **all the EC2 instances** in a specific region and keeping the old ones in place?

Comment: It should be possible to script this using the CLI.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do: get the list of EC2 instance and then modify SG list? But the question is still valid - will the existing ones be preserved during the modification or will be dropped?

Comment: You'll need to loop through the instances, get their current SG settings, and add to that. The CLI appears to expect the full list.

Comment: Again, for volume: ***The CLI expects the full list of ALL SGs for the instance.*** If you only give it one SG that will be the _only_ SG on the instances and you'll have to go back through and add your SGs back like I did.